# Google Sheets JavaScript error "missing name after . operator"

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

The error I am getting is:

> missing name after . operator

I get it when debugging/running my code on line 10.  Anyone know the workaround?

```
1    function codebook_level() {
2      
3      if(!require(pacman)) {
4      install.packages("pacman"); require(pacman)}
5    p_load(magrittr, data.table)
6    require(dplyr)
7    
8    
9    read_add_name_col <- function(file){
10      rn <- gsub(".csv", "", file, ignore.case=T)
11      spl <- strsplit(rn, "/") %>% unlist()
12      svy <- spl[length(spl)]
13      df <- fread(file)
14      df$survey_series <- svy
15      return(df)
....
```

Comment: What error are you getting? And what is the script supposed to do?

Comment: The error is in the title but that has been solved.  Now getting a generic "syntax" error on the same line.  The complete code is meant to pull geographies from another sheet by level to determine if it exists in that other sheet and at what granularity.

Answer (score 1):

`<-` is not a JavaScript operator. It will be parsed as the `<` comparison operator followed by `-`.

But amazingly, that's not the problem, though it's probably **a** problem. Google Sheets implements a language *very much like* JavaScript circa ES3 (so, a long time back) though not quite the same. Back then, you couldn't use keywords as property name literals. So the specific problem in the title of your question is here:

```
rn <- gsub(".csv", "", file, ignore.case=T)
// ---------------------------------^
```

To access a property called `case` prior to the ES5 specification's changes to the grammar, you had to use brackets notation and a string: `ignore["case"]` instead of `ignore.case`.

But again, that's just the error in the question; the code overall looks to probably have other issues, unless `<-` is some kind of Sheets language extension.

---

> I did edit the "case" to [case] so that solved that but now I am getting a generic "syntax" error on the same line.

Well, yes. You have to deal with the various other issues around the `<-` that isn't meant to be there and other non-JavaScript-isms. It's impressive that the parser was able to get that far, really, but the `sp1` token on the next line just completely kills it

It looks like `<-` is meant to be `=` and `rn` and such are meant to be variables. If so:

- Use the `=` (assignment) operator
- Declare the variables, so you don't fall prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*

It's also worth noting that

```
gsub(".csv", "", file, ignore.case=T)
```

...looks a **lot** like it's trying to use a named parameter. JavaScript doesn't have named parameters, what that code really does is:

```
ignore.case=T
gsub(".csv", "", file, T)
```

...but only evaluating `T` once.

Comment: The <- bit isn't an extension.  It is form the original script that I made the mistake of thinking would be a more literal translation into sheets. I did edit the "case" to [case] so that solved that but now I am getting a generic "syntax" error on the same line.

Comment: @DennisLaviolette: That's because the `sp1` on the next line doesn't make sense to the parser. The code isn't, remotely, correct JavaScript/Google Sheets Script. I suggest studying the language and converting the code into it. I've added a couple of notes above.